# Read only user in Subversion

Tags: apache, svn

I am testing SVN user for the read only access: following are is the configuration that I have in apache2 and svn repo conf:

However my test user have read and write access, instead I want read only access.

```
repo location
/svn/test/
```

file:  /etc/apache2/conf.d/svn.conf

```
<location /repos>
   DAV svn 
   #svn path
   SVNParentPath /svn/
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Authorization Realm"
   #password file path
   AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/test.users
   Require valid-user
</location>
```

authz conf (only one entry) 
file: /svn/test/conf/authz

```
[test:/svn/test/]
* = r
```

also tried: following

```
[groups]
readonly = user1, user2

[/]
*=r
@readonly=r
```

also tried: following
    [groups]
    readonly = user1, user2

```
[10.29.3.238:80/repos/test]
*=r
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

- You have authz-file, but **don't use it**: you [miss at least one directive](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/mod_authz_svn/INSTALL) in SVN-location

`AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/test/conf/authz`

- You last authz-file is wrongly-formatted: path-section **must** have format without URL or IP of host, only `[repository-name:/path/on/this/repo]` (`[/]`is special case). I.e for `[test:/svn/test/]` after adding AuthzSVNAccessFile you define folder /svn/test/ in repository test as RO for everybody, second attempt is excessive: `* = r` will define all repositories RO for everybody, `@readonly = r` also RO for additional group (which is part of "Everybody" `*`)